# Why do most FIFO chips have a 9-bit bus?

Tags: fifo, parity

For example, on DigiKey, many FIFO memory chips have 9-bit or 18-bit words:
https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/logic-fifos-memory/707

Is this to be used as a parity bit? It just seems strange to me that most other memory chips do use 8-bit buses but FIFOs specifically seem to mostly be 9-bit, so I want to make sure I'm not missing something important.

Comment: Parity???????????

Comment: You should give at least one example to clarify what you mean by "FIFIO chip".

Comment: Literally from a datasheet of a random chip from your link: *"The devices utilize a 9-bit wide data array to allow for control and parity bits
at the user’s option. This feature is especially useful in data communications
applications where it is necessary to use a parity bit for transmission/reception
error checking"*

Comment: @EugeneSh. That was from an edit from CL. Not the original author.

Comment: @horta Oh, OK. Not sure  this edit is aligned with the OP intention though

Comment: No, that aligns with my intention. I had clicked several data sheets and Ctrl+F'd for "parity" without much luck, but you are right that one of the first results in that list does explain that.

Comment: You might want to find out why your pdf reader does not work with ^f

Comment: It probably finds its roots back some military protocol that used parity and stemmed from there.

Answer (score 2):

@EugeneSh pointed out that [this data sheet](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/document/dst/7203-7208-datasheet) mentions parity specifically:

> The device's 9-bit width provides a bit for a control or parity at the user’s option